# For Zybook lab assignment : error message: ValueError: Format specifier missing precision

Tags: python-3.x, format

```
#input user values
user_input = input()

#split a string
tokens = user_input.split()
#add tokens to a list

input_data = []
for tokens in tokens:
    input_data.append(int(tokens))

sum =0
average =0
max =0
for i in input_data:
   sum = sum + i               *I am getting an error message here too something about built in function.
   if i > max:
        max = i
average = sum/len(input_data)
print('{:.of} {}'.format(average, max)) ***getting error message "format specifier missing precision****
```

I followed along the[picture of class instruction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bsb6P.png) lesson I have received from my professor for instruction in zybooks

I am supposed to input 5 20 0 5
with output : 10 20

Comment: Hello, and welcome to StackOveflow. `max()` is actually a `built-in` Python function the returns the maximum value of the list. So replace max with another variable name.

Comment: An example would be `something = [1,2,4]` and `max(something)` would return 4. I hope that helps.